# Can I run Google TV add-on emulation on Windows by hook or by crook?

Tags: java, android, windows, linux

Although I know that Google TV emulation is currently supported on Linux with KVM only, but I want to know that can it be possible to run this on windows OS by any way like by setting up a virtual Linux OS with KVM on windows. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you found answer about your question? Because I also want to some full proof answer about that.